# improving redundant if else query (maybe with design pattern?) AND reduce global variables?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, global

My code works fine, but it seems for me very amateurish.

1)
For example: I'm working with bluetooth and I have always to check, whether there is a device and if the user has a connection.

```
 if isThereADevice != nil && isThereADevice.connected() {
   //do stuff via bluetooth
 } else {
   //do an alternative
 }
```

This construct exists > 25 in my "project". It would be cool to find a better solution, but my coding experience isn't so good. I would be happy to get some information, code snippets or ideas, which I can google :)

2)
The 2nd stupid thing is, that I have a lot global variables. This doesn't look like good style.

For example: In the game at the beginning the user pick a stone. This stone has an ID. Overall I have five UIViewController and in every UIViewController I need this ID.

I just created just a Globals.swift and define:

```
var globalID: String = "default"
```

Meanwhile I have > 20 global variables like time, rounds, some objects... When do I use globals in Swift? Do I use them? 
What is an solution for my ID-problem?

Answer (score 1):

Without more context it's hard to give a solid answer to your question, but hopefully what I'm about to say will lead you down the right path.

It sounds like you have a Bluetooth service in which there needs to be one and only one of it's type. This *may* be a good opportunity to use a singleton pattern to represent the Bluetooth service. You could also use a delegate pattern to interface with the Bluetooth service from various entities in your application.

**More Information:**

- [Singleton Pattern in Swift](http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton)
- [Singleton Design Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html)
- [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)
- [Delegates and Data Sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)

As far as global scope in iOS goes, avoid it. Structs are meant to represent values in Swift, use them to store your values!

For example:

```
struct UIConstants {
    var color           = UIColor.blackColor()
    var height: CGFloat = 10
}
```

You can now use this anywhere:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    let constants = UIConstants()

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = constants.color
    }
}
```

That way these values can be reused, and changed in one location if you ever needed to apply changes to all the entities in your application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just out of interesse: Why do I have to avoid global scopes? I read your links and got a solution with a Singleton. But where is the difference? My code works with both solution.

Answer (score 0):

For part one create a bluetooth helper class with some static functions that do this check for you and takes in some blocks

```
class BluetoothHelper {
   class func doStuffViaBluetooth(bluetoothDeviceAvailible: () -> (), bluetoothDeviceUnavailible: () -> ())
      if isThereADevice != nil && isThereADevice.connected() {
         bluetoothDeviceAvailible()
      } else {
        bluetoothDeviceUnavailible()
     }
}
```

this could then be called like so

```
BluetoothHelper.doStuffViaBluetooth(bluetoothDeviceAvailible: {
   //Do Bluetooth stuff
}, bluetoothDeviceUnavailible: {
  //Handle error case
})
```

This doesn't reduce the number of lines in your code it will in fact increase them slightly but this is far more abstracted and you are only implementing the logic of testing for the device once. This is also much easier for you to test.

As for answer two I would suggest creating a data model with objects like Player and Rounds and passing these objects between view controllers.